# ASP.Net Select a Dropdown option (in View) based on a value returned by EF model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

For a Dropdown (as a SelectList) in my View, I can successfully set the value to the Id returned by my model, but the list does not update to reflect the selected Id as the selected item.

```
<%var type = Model.CompanyTypeId; %>
<%= Html.DropDownList("Type", (ViewData["Types"] as SelectList),
        new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "class", "form-control form-input"},
                { "Id", "CoType"},
                { "Name", "CoType"},
                { "value", type },
                { "option", "selected" }
             })%>
```

I expect the dropdown list to update the selected item to the corresponding Id

(In ChromeDev tools I can verify the Id=Model.CompanyTypeId and option="selected", but the dropdown list still shows the item selected by default.

I expect the dropdown list to update the selected item to the corresponding Id

(In ChromeDev tools I can verify the Id=Model.CompanyTypeId and option="selected", but the dropdown list still shows the item selected by default.

```
    <select id="CoType" name="CoType" class="form-control form-input" 
     option="selected" value="1">
        <option value="-1">- Assign Type - </option>
        <option value="1">Dummy</option>
        <option value="2">Test CompanyType</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `Model.CompanyTypeId`, you can easily use `Html.DropDownListFor`. You don't set value on the HTML attributes.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new TestModel
    {
        CompanyTypeId = 1
    };

    ViewBag.Types = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "-1", Text = "-- Assign Type --" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Dummy" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Test" },
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyTypeId, 
    (ViewBag.Types as List<SelectListItem>),
    new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "class", "form-control form-input"},
        { "Id", "CoType"},
        { "Name", "CoType"}
     })
```